# How to convert bytes into megabits in Java?

Tags: java

I have a PCAP file and I am writing a script to get details from the packet trace. I am trying to find the average bandwidth of the packet trace and I am stuck on converting a certain amount of **bytes into megabits**. I know 8 bits = 1 byte, and 1 Megabyte = 10^6 bytes, but am confused on how to implement such a conversion in Java.

Comment: There are 1024 bits per megabit (also, remember, there is a difference between mega bits and mega bytes ;)) so it's simple mathematical process, `bits / 1024.0` will give you megabits (ie `1024 / 1024.0` is 1.0 mbit).  You can reverse it with `mbits * 1024.0` as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer did you mean 1024 bits per *kilobit*?

Comment: @tgdavies Yes, sorry, mbits is 1024 * 1024

Comment: What problem are you having implementing this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons library for this

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#byteCountToDisplaySize(long)

Comment: I think the OP probably wants the result as a long rather than a String.

Comment: Thanks :) . 
Then it would be simply performing division to get from bit to mbit.